# HTML email tables broken in Outlook 2007 & 2010

Tags: html-table, html-email, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I have an email template that works fine in most email clients (or at least acceptable), but completely breaks in Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010.

I'm aware that these versions of Outlook use the Word rendering engine instead of IE.

I've heard of the Outlook page break bug, but that seems to only affect vertical spacing. My issue is in horizontal spacing.

**Code:** http://jsbin.com/alagih/edit#html,liveb

**Test results for all major email clients:** http://artletic.createsend.com/screens/y/F2B9C33F1297A73F

**Outlook 2007 screenshot:**
[image: Outlook 2007 screenshot]

Comment: Start debugging: Remove all the amazonaws-hosted images. Then start removing style definitions. Eventually you'll find the one that's making Word barf.

Comment: Thanks @marc-b. I've tried a number of variations, but was hoping to avoid testing 50 different times. I'm using CampaignMonitor's testing (which uses Litmus). $5 per test is good for a few, but when debugging, that adds up quick!

Comment: Shouldn't be any real reason you can't whip up a quick test script with the raw html hard-coded and work on that to your own mailbox without involving third parties. If you can't replicate it with that separate script, then start screaming at vendors.

Comment: @MarcB I could if I had a PC with Outlook. :)

Answer (score 5):

I have found that specifically for HTML emails in outlook 2007, you should set your width parameters in both the tag and inline CSS.

so for example `<td width="150px" style="width: 150px;">`

Comment: Helped me with outlook 2010 too. Nice one

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a width to any td that contains an image.

Example:

```
<td width="150">
    <img src="/img/image.jpg" width="150" height="150">
</td>
```

Also make sure these images are set to `display: block`.

Answer (score 1):

You never set a width for the table containing your body message.

It's set to `<table border="0" width="">`

As for your "franco.jpg" image, looks like Outlook is ignoring the inline margin on the `img` tag. Try creating a two-column table for your content and either wrap the image in a div and give it a right margin or wrap your text content in a div and give it a left margin. Outlook doesn't like padding for some reason.

Also since Outlook 2007 and probably 2010 is using Word as a rendering engine, it will ignore certain styles such as `background-image` (background-position, too), it will however, accept `bgcolor' and 'background-color'.

The quickest way to test for Outlook 2007/2010 would be to open it up in MS Word. It should render close to what would appear in those Outlook versions.

Not sure what's causing the `=E2=80=9D`.

If you really must use background images, try [this hack](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3192/add-a-background-image-to-individual-table-cells/).

Comment: [There's a new 'hack' for including background images](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3363/updated-applying-a-background-image-to-html-email) at the same site referenced in your original "this hack" link.